# How check if multicast socket is occupied?

Tags: c#, networking, multicastsocket

I need to send some stream on multicast.
Is there some way to check ( from the code ) is some multicast socket is occupied by someone else on the network that i connected to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing. Multicast can be one to many or many to one. Depends on your application/problem. Usually a sender just sends to a group:port and receivers join to listen.